# Audiowerk 8 drivers for Linux

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, audio

Does a driver exist for the old Audiowerk 8 sound card from now defunct Emagic?
I have a system running Ubuntu 13.10 and would like to utilize one of these old sound cards.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search yielded this:   http://home.gna.org/aw2-alsa/